# Custom Outlook Meeting Notice Form from Shared Calendar

Tags: forms, vba, vbscript, outlook, ms-office

I am trying to create an appointment/meeting notice template that prevents forwarding, defaults to no response required and is sent from a delegated/shared calendar.  I have the script to change the response required and can disable the forwarding option in the actions, but I can't figure out the delegate.  I've found the getname script:

```
Sub ResolveName()
    Dim myNamespace As Outlook.NameSpace
    Dim myRecipient As Outlook.Recipient
    Dim CalendarFolder As Outlook.Folder

    Set myNamespace = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set myRecipient = myNamespace.CreateRecipient("Larry M Garrett")
    myRecipient.Resolve
    If myRecipient.Resolved Then
        Call ShowCalendar(myNamespace, myRecipient)
    End If
End Sub

Sub ShowCalendar(myNamespace, myRecipient)
    Dim CalendarFolder As Outlook.Folder

    Set CalendarFolder = _
        myNamespace.GetSharedDefaultFolder _
        (myRecipient, olFolderCalendar)
    CalendarFolder.Display
End Sub
```

This works in visual basic, but it only opens the shared calendar.  It doesn't set the appointment to come from the shared calendar.  I get a code error if i put it into the "view code" section and try to run the form.  I feel like i'm missing the step where i tell it to send from the delegated calendar but i can't find it.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need to use the shared calendar folder to create an appointment item. Use the [sharedCalendarFolder.Items.Add](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff861028(v=office.15).aspx) method to create an appointment.

Comment: It looks like i need the specifics of the appointment in the code to use items.add.  I have a form i created in outlook that has code to remove the response request, and has disabled forwarding.  I need to use this template often but from a calendar that's shared with me instead of from my own calendar.  I can't find a code that lets me set it to come from that shared calendar.